# Getting the version of the current clojure project in the repl

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Is it possible to grab the project information within the clojure repl?

For example, if there was a project defined:

```
(defproject blahproject "0.1.2" ....)
```

When running a repl in the project directory, is there a function like this?

```
> (project-version) 
;=> 0.1.2
```

Comment: If you just want the project version, it is mentioned here:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235445/embed-version-string-from-leiningen-project-in-application

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Leiningen project files are just Clojure data :)

`(-> "/path/to/project.clj" slurp read-string (nth 2))`

Comment: Just use `(some-> (io/resource "project.clj") slurp edn/read-string (nth 2))`

Comment: @joelittlejohn Chances of getting arbitrary project.clj from your classpath considered high. I got clj-time/clj-time and I haven't even explicitly pulled in that library. Be careful reaching into darkened boxes to withdraw an item at random.

Comment: @pete23 Good point. If you built your jar with lein then you can also use `(some->> (io/resource "META-INF/maven/myproject/myproject/pom.properties") slurp (re-find #"version=(.*)") second)`

Answer (score 18):

While you can parse `project.clj` yourself, this may be annoying. It's also a lot of work. Instead, you can just do:

```
(System/getProperty "projectname.version")
```

Comment: Works from the repl, but not in an uberjar.

Comment: @DanRoss so this could be used to detect if the current program was started from a repl? Or is there an easier/more reliable way?

Answer (score 11):

I use environ (https://github.com/weavejester/environ) which sucks in settings from a number of sources, including system properties. The project version appears as `:<project-name>-version`:

```
foobar.repl=> (require '[environ.core :refer [env]])
nil
foobar.repl=> (:foobar-version env)
"0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Answer (score 9):

Add the below code to the end of project.clj:

```
(def project (assoc-in project [:repl-options :init]
                       `(~'def ~'project-version ~(project :version))))
```

Now you will have a var called `project-version` in the initial namespace for the repl.

Answer (score 9):

As described in this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leiningen/7G24ifiYvOA).

```
(ns myproject.example
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:import java.util.Properties))

(defn get-version [dep]
  (let [path (str "META-INF/maven/" (or (namespace dep) (name dep))
                  "/" (name dep) "/pom.properties")
        props (io/resource path)]
    (when props
      (with-open [stream (io/input-stream props)]
        (let [props (doto (Properties.) (.load stream))]
          (.getProperty props "version"))))))

(get-version 'myproject) ; => 0.1.0
(get-version 'org.clojure/clojure) ; => 1.3.0
```

Answer (score 7):

As [vemv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270805/how-to-get-the-version-of-the-current-clojure-project-in-the-repl/16272358#16272358) said, Leiningen project files are just Clojure data. So, it's easy to access your project as an ordinary `hash-map`:

```
(->> "project.clj"
     slurp
     read-string
     (drop 2)
     (cons :version)
     (apply hash-map)
     (def project))
```

If you need this variable only in your `repl`, you can add it to `repl-options` to your `project.clj`:

```
(defproject yourproject "0.1.0"
  :description ""
  :url ""
  :dependencies [ [org.clojure/clojure  "1.4.0"]]
  :repl-options { :init (->>  "project.clj"
                              slurp
                              read-string
                              (drop 2)
                              (cons :version)
                              (apply hash-map)
                              (def project))})
```

Now, you have `project` variable in your `repl`. So, to access the version of your project you can simply type `(:version project)`.

Of course, you can simply use native Leiningen code to parse you project file:

```
(defproject yourproject "0.1.0"
  :description ""
  :url ""
  :dependencies [ [org.clojure/clojure  "1.4.0"]
                  [leiningen-core       "2.1.3"]]
  :repl-options { :init (do (require 'leiningen.core.project)
                            (def project
                                 (leiningen.core.project/read)))})
```

But, if you need only the version of your project and nothing more, then it's best to use [Ankur's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270805/how-to-get-the-version-of-the-current-clojure-project-in-the-repl/16274279#16274279) solution.

Answer (score 7):

For a more fully-featured approach, you might want to take a look at the configleaf plugin for Leiningen (https://github.com/davidsantiago/configleaf). It will make the project map, with active profiles merged in, available to project code in a namespace of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to do this from clojurescript you could create a macro (from another clj file) and call it from the cljs code :

```
;;ex: macro.clj
(defmacro get-project-version [] 
  (System/getProperty "penelope.version"))

;;my_logic_code.cljs
(ns my-logic-code
  (:require-macros [macros :as m]))

(def project-version (m/get-project-version))
```