# How to access values on leiningen profiles?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I've got a two profiles defined in project.clj, one locally, one for testing on travis:

```
:profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[midje "1.6.0"]
                                [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.25"]]
                 :plugins [[lein-midje "3.1.3"]]
                 :user "root" :pass "root"}
           :travis {:user "travis" :pass ""}}
```

I'm hoping to be able to get access to the :user and :pass values in my projects. How can this be done?

Update:

I also want to be able to use the `lein with-profile` command... so my tests would have:

```
lein with-profile dev test
```

-> would use "root", "root" credentials

```
lein with-profile dev,travis test
```

-> would use "travis", "" credentials

Comment: I think this problem it's resolved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270805/how-to-get-the-version-of-the-current-clojure-project-in-the-repl

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't need the values defined in `project.clj` for anything else (IE, you're free to choose the representation) consider [Environ](https://github.com/weavejester/environ).

You can then define the following in your project.clj

```
:profiles {:dev {:env {:user "root" :pass "root"}}}
```

and read the values:

```
(use 'environ.core)

(def creds
  {:user (env :user)
   :pass (env :pass)})
```

This has the advantage that you can also specify the values using environment variables and system properties.

Answer (score 7):

Leiningen's build file is Clojure code so you can just read it in:

```
(->> "project.clj" slurp read-string (drop 3) (partition 2) (map vec) (into {})
     :profiles :dev)
; => {:dependencies [[midje "1.5.1"] [ring-server "0.2.8"]], :plugins [[lein-midje "3.1.0"]]}
```

If you need heavier functionalities (such as access to the final project map) then something like [configleaf](https://github.com/davidsantiago/configleaf) might be better suited.

Another way to manage this (which I've utilized quite often) is to have a separate config file for profile specific data:

`example/profiles/travis/example/config.clj`:

```
(ns example.config)

(def user "travis")
(def pass "")
```

`example/dev-resources/example/config.clj`:

```
(ns example.config)

(def user "root")
(def pass "root")
```

`example/src/example/core.clj`:

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [example.config :as config]))

(println config/user)
```

And you need to add the profile specific resource path to your `project.clj`:

```
:profiles {:travis {:resource-paths ["profiles/travis/"]}}
```

Comment: I've updated my question. it is dependent on the chosen profile

Comment: @zcaudate, then you could try `configleaf`, it provides access to the final project map which has the selected profile merged in.

Comment: @zcaudate, I added another way to handle your use case, this does not require additional dependencies.

Comment: thanks for the two ways of configuring profiles. I'm going to select the eniron answer as that was the one that I used to implement the travis ci - https://github.com/zcaudate/manas but I upvoted and will definitely be using your approach on bigger projects.