# Can I lookup things within a Lein Project in the REPL?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Say I have a vanilla project.clj like

```
(defproject myservice "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :mailing-list {:name "myservice@example.com" :post "myservice@climate.com"}
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url  "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.4.0"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.4.0"]
                 [compojure "1.4.0"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.5"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.logging "0.3.1"]
                 [clj-http "2.0.0"]]

  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.9.7"]]

  :ring {:handler myservice.core/standalone-app
         :port 3000}
  :profiles {
             :uberjar {:ring {:handler myservice.core/app}}}
  )
```

In a `lein repl`, can I lookup values from the project.clj?  How?  Of course my blind hack didn't work?

```
user=> (:mailing-list project)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: project in this context, compiling:(/private/var/folders/1g/fnytl2x93sx6hp2f1rsf4h1r5xtqv_/T/form-init6671981825845237047.clj:1:1)
```

The follow on question is can I use stuff from the project map further on in the project.clj?  Like if I wanted to pull that mailing list :name out and substitute it in as a :deb :maintainer?

```
:deb 
  {:toDir "target"
   :package "mysevice"
   :maintainer {:name "Meeples", :email "myservice@example.com"}
   ...
  }
```

I'm sure you can tell, I'm kind-of new to this, but the project.clj is just executable Clojure, no?  If I knew the name of the project's map, I should be able to query it, right?

Comment: This is not an answer, but [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270805/how-to-get-the-version-of-the-current-clojure-project-in-the-repl) presents a couple of solutions that could work for your use case, such as slurping the project.clj or `def`-ing out the parts you're interested in.

Comment: Hmmm.  This isn't so simple, is it?  I guess I should ask a different question.  What I am really trying to do is to pull a value out of the :mailing-list map and use it as the :email value in :deb, :maintainer.

Comment: Oh in that case you can `def` stuff - let me do a proper answer, 2 secs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `def` data as you usually would and include them using `~`

```
(def mailing-list {:name "myservice@example.com" :post "myservice@climate.com"})

(defproject myservice "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :mailing-list ~mailing-list
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url  "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.4.0"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.4.0"]
                 [compojure "1.4.0"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.5"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.logging "0.3.1"]
                 [clj-http "2.0.0"]]

  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.9.7"]]

  :ring {:handler myservice.core/standalone-app
         :port 3000}
  :profiles {
             :uberjar {:ring {:handler myservice.core/app}}}
  :deb {
        :toDir "target"
        :package "mysevice"
        :maintainer {:name "Meeples", :email (:name ~mailing-list)}})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant line in leiningen : https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/b29b2ea41b6d177a8a57493b979164eab0931e4d/leiningen-core/src/leiningen/core/project.clj#L405

Given the namespace is `leiningen.core.project`, the map should be under it.

Comment: Actually because `defproject` is a macro, it will create the `project` in the namespace of the call site...which we're not sure of

Comment: @acron Interesting, I was not aware of that. A bit more code digging then^^