# How to get project-version in Travis-CI

Tags: clojure, travis-ci

I have a Clojure project that I build and test with Travis-CI. I can upload the artifact (a .jar-file) back to my Github-account, but I need to remove the version-number. As long as the filename is known it is easy but I would like to be able to use the version number from the project.clj-file.

So the question:
How to configure .travis.yml to fetch the version number from project.clj in my Clojure project, to be able to use it later in the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several options available here, depending on exactly how you're building the project.

[how to get the version of the current clojure project in the repl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270805/how-to-get-the-version-of-the-current-clojure-project-in-the-repl)

[Embed version string from leiningen project in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235445/embed-version-string-from-leiningen-project-in-application)